# Heroku with Laravel - "make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled"

Tags: php, heroku, redis

I am new to using Heroku and general web hosting etc. 
In my project I am using redis which means I need php-redis too for them to be able to communicate. 
The issue is that I cannot find much documentation about how to enable the extension/install it onto my Heroku server.

If anyone could help or explain that would be amazing :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding "ext-redis": "version number X". to my composer.json which was then installed by Heroku automatically.

Hope this helps anyone! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use phpinfo() for this. Try also phpversion('redis').

If you want to install separately then,

```
Try to use this url https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/3.1.4.zip

wget https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/3.1.4.zip -O phpredis.zip

cd phpredis && phpize && ./configure && make && sudo make install

add this to php.ini file extension = redis.so and restart php and apache or ngnix.
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I managed to fix this by adding "ext-redis" to my composer.json file. Heroku installed for me and it worked! :D

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the `redis.so` file and this helped me get it.